# Find the general solution to the differential equation $x^2 y'' + 6xy' + 4y = x^{-1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We know that its associated homogeneous equation is a second-order Euler equation. Letting $x=e^t$, we get

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+5\frac{dy}{dt}+y=0$$

which has as a general solution $y(t)= c_1 e^{-t} + c_2 e^{-4}$. If $t=\ln x$, then $y(x)= c_1 x^{-1} + c_2 x^{-4}$. How can I find a particular solution to the nonhomogeneous equation?

$$e^{2t}y'' + 6e^t y' + 4y = e^{-t} $$

Do I have to divide it by $e^{2t}$? I've tried to anticipate a solution of the form $(A+Bt)e^{-t}$ but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it directly using exact differentials in this case.

$$LHS=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y'+4xy)$$
,Integrating on both sides with respect to $x$, we get,
$$x^2y'+4xy=\log x+c$$
Now directly apply method of integrating factors to get general solution.

Answer (score 0):

For solving the homogeneous equation $$x^2 y'' + 6xy' + 4y = 0$$ let $y=x^k$ and you will find solutions $$y=x^{-1}\text { and }  y=x^{-4}$$

For particular solution use the method of variation of parameters. $$y_p = u_1x^{-1} + u_2 x^{-4}$$

and solve for $u_1$ and $u_2$

Answer (score 0):

The equation becomes once you substitute $x=e^t$ :
$$y''+5y'+4y=e^{-t}$$
The solution to the homogeneous equation is 
$$(r+4)(r+1)=0 \implies y_h=c_1e^{-4t}+c_2e^{-t}$$
For the inhomogenous equation, you have to try a particular solution like $Ate^{-t}$ :

$$\implies A=\frac 1 3$$
$$y=c_1e^{-4t}+c_2e^{-t}+\frac 1 3 te^{-t}$$
Since $t=\ln x$
$$y=c_1x^{-4}+c_2x^{-1}+\frac 1 3 x^{-1}\ln x$$